# Where are continous latitude and longitude on Google Earth?

Tags: google-earth

Last summer I opened Google Earth to a satellite image, as usual, where the position of the cursor was continuously updated to show long. and lat. in overlay at the periphery of the screen.  This also had dots showing where people had uploaded pictures from the location.  Now I cannot find either feature.  Where do I go for this?  Did it die with New Google Maps?  To clarify, I first opened Google Maps to the area I wanted (town), then clicked on the "earth" option, which takes me to Google Earth. But now there's no continuous cursory lat/long designation nor are there the circles you can click on to find user photos at the location.

Comment: Google Earth and New Google Maps should still be separate entities as far as I'm aware. Are you actually looking for Google Earth features in Google Maps? Or just concerned with the seemingly missing features coming about in the same timeframe as New Google maps coming out?

Answer (score 1):

**Finding the photos like old Google Maps**

Here is a gif to illustrate how to view the photos:

[image: Demo GIF]

---

**Finding the Lat and Long - Updated Answer at Bottom**

To get the lat and long it is a little more complicated. Look at the URL. The one shown in the gif above has the following URL:

```
https://www.google.ca/maps/preview#!q=Moses+Springer+Park&data=!1m4!1m3!1d46929!2d-80.5184007!3d43.4739984!4m32!2m14!1m13!1s0x0%3A0x145b19312461b8bb!3m8!1m3!1d11732!2d-80.5308033!3d43.4747147!3m2!1i787!2i389!4f13.1!4m2!3d43.4736755!4d-80.5111974!5m16!2m15!1m14!1s0x89d4cb90d7c63ba5%3A0x323555502ab4c477!2sToronto%2C+Ontario!3m8!1m3!1d88307!2d-80.527934!3d43.475226!3m2!1i1440!2i732!4f13.1!4m2!3d43.653226!4d-79.3831843
```

If you look at the end of the URL there is the following found at the end of it:

```
43.653226!4d-79.3831843
```

This means the lat and long of Moses Springer Park is:

**Lat**: `43.653226`

**Long**: `-79.3831843`

**Edited answer for update:**

Google maps has made an update, and now it is much easier to get coordinates. Simply click on a location and coordinates will be displayed. Take a look at the following image for an example

[image: example of coords]

Answer (score 0):

I know it has been some time since the question was posted.  I came across it as I had the same problem.

I came across what I believe to be the answer to the original inquiry.

Using Google Earth, the "Status Bar" must be on.  When it is activated a continuous display of the latitude and longitude coordinates of the cursor is displayed, along with the "eye altitude."

The Status Bar can be activated within the drop down menu under the "View" tab, the third tab from the left at the top of the Google Earth screen.